# How to define the command for a button with a variable

Tags: java, button, onclicklistener

At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to make a method in my java program set what a button in my project does when is is clicked.

I was thinking about something like

`myButton.addClickHandler(event -> command);`

where `command´ is a String variable.

Is this even possible? I am thankful for every response!

Comment: What technology are you using? Is this a website(javascript), a Swing app, Android, other?

Answer (score 0):

Can a button itself access the information and check what needs to be done?
If so, you can always add an `ActionListener` and implement its method `actionPerfomed` which is going to be called when button is pressed.

Comment: Also, if you need to change the behaviour of your button dynamically, you can always remove and add another listener with different implementation of `actionPerformed`